# Google SignIn API Exception 10 when compile on another computer

Tags: android, google-signin

The Google SignIn inside my Android app runs perfectly well (I can sign in using any Google accounts on the phone) when I compiled the code in my daily-laptop. But when I cloned the code in my other laptop and compiled it there, it will always return `Code 10` error.

Here's the full `e.printStackTrace()`

```
 W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:8)
 W/System.err:     at com.imincode.earthlings.view.ui.Register.onActivityResult(Register.kt:443)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4839)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4887)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

In my console.developers.google.com Project Credentials, under Application restrictions I chose Android apps and I've triple confirmed that I put the correct `SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint` from both my daily computer and this other laptop.

Edit: And I can confirm that `google-services.json` is there under `app` folder on both machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the SHA Key to your project in your firebase , Go To :

Project Overview -> Click on Settings Icon -> Project Settings -> General -> Scroll down under your package name -> Add your SHA key